# MSQQL Merge replication issue (MSSQL 2008R2)

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue that I have seen lots of questions relating too, but no answers solving.

I have a server (lets call it DBSERVER) and a client (lets call it DBCLIENT).  The server is running MSSQL 2008R2 standard, the client is running MSSQL 2008R2 express.

I am trying to set up a merge replication between the two.

I have set up by publisher(and distributor) on the server.  Following the MSTN article (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337384(v=sql.105).aspx).  This means I have 4 users on the server.  DBSERVER\repl_distribution and DBSERVER\repl_merge are the most important I think.  Both these (and the other 2) ARE db_owner of the merge DB source.

I have set up a subscription on the DBCLIENT, and I have made sure that DBCLIENT\repl_merge is a db_owner.

The database is set up (but contains no data).  The subscription LOOKS normal, until you look at the properties and you see that under "Status of last synchronisation" is "The agent has never been run".

OK - so right click on "launch replication monitor" on DBCLIENT, attach publisher, and under "publications" the status is "OK".  Under the specific subscription, the status is "Uninitalized subscription" and the connection is "unknown".  Before I go on to say that I have tried to "reinitalize" countless times - The agent history shows that the snapshot WAS created successfully, and there are no warnings or errors in the agent history at all.  I can also start the agent from the menu and watch it create another snapshot - but still no joy.

I have used "net use" to make sure that the user details I provided have access to the repl folder on the server (they do).  I have made sure that the DBCLIENT\repl_merge user has access to the MSSQL server AND the merged database.

Any help or advice would be great here as all other advise has not done anything.